# Remote Video stream not showing up at all

Tags: javascript, socket.io, webrtc

I have been trying to get the remote video stream to show up using .ontrack which is under the peer connection function in my code. Until now the .ontrack only fires on the caller side while on the callee it does not even when the function is called.

The log that checks if .ontrack fires would state "Got Remote Stream" but only on the caller side which might be the problem here but I'm not sure why would the other party not go into the IF statement that holds the .ontrack when it does not have the event.stream[0] which the statement is checking for.

I have added the console logs from both Caller and Callee below. Not shown in the images is that after a while the candidates would show null but both users are still connected.

**main.js**

```
'use strict';

var isInitiator;
var configuration = {
  iceServers: [
    {
      urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
    }
  ]
};
var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);

// Define action buttons.
const callButton = document.getElementById('callButton');
const hangupButton = document.getElementById('hangupButton');

/////////////////////////////////////////////

window.room = prompt('Enter room name:');

var socket = io.connect();

if (room !== '') {
  console.log('Message from client: Asking to join room ' + room);
  socket.emit('create or join', room);
}

socket.on('created', function(room) {
  console.log('Created room ' + room);
  isInitiator = true;
  startVideo();
});

socket.on('full', function(room) {
  console.log('Message from client: Room ' + room + ' is full :^(');
});

socket.on('joined', function(room) {
  console.log('joined: ' + room);
  startVideo();
  callButton.disabled = true;
});

socket.on('log', function(array) {
  console.log.apply(console, array);
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////

async function sendMessage(message) {
  console.log('Client sending message: ', message);
  await socket.emit('message', message);
}

// This client receives a message
socket.on('message', async function(message) {
  try {
    if (message.type === 'offer') {
      await pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
      await pc
        .setLocalDescription(await pc.createAnswer())
        .then(function() {
          sendMessage(pc.localDescription);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err.name + ': ' + err.message);
        });
      createPeerConnection();
    } else if (message.type === 'answer') {
      await pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
    } else if (message.type === 'candidate') {
      await pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const localVideo = document.querySelector('#localVideo');
const remoteVideo = document.querySelector('#remoteVideo');

// Set up initial action buttons status: disable call and hangup.
callButton.disabled = true;
hangupButton.disabled = true;

// Add click event handlers for buttons.
callButton.addEventListener('click', callStart);
hangupButton.addEventListener('click', hangupCall);

function startVideo() {
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({
      audio: true,
      video: true
    })
    .then(function(stream) {
      localVideo.srcObject = stream;
      stream.getTracks().forEach(track => pc.addTrack(track, stream));
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('getUserMedia() error: ' + err.name);
    });
  callButton.disabled = false;
}

async function callStart() {
  createPeerConnection();
  callButton.disabled = true;
  hangupButton.disabled = false;
  if (isInitiator) {
    console.log('Sending offer to peer');
    await pc
      .setLocalDescription(await pc.createOffer())
      .then(function() {
        sendMessage(pc.localDescription);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err.name + ': ' + err.message);
      });
  }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function createPeerConnection() {
  try {
    pc.ontrack = event => {
      if (remoteVideo.srcObject !== event.streams[0]) {
        remoteVideo.srcObject = event.streams[0];
        console.log('Got remote stream');
      }
    };
    pc.onicecandidate = ({ candidate }) => sendMessage({ candidate });
    console.log('Created RTCPeerConnnection');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Failed to create PeerConnection, exception: ' + e.message);
    alert('Cannot create RTCPeerConnection object.');
    return;
  }
}

function hangupCall() {
  pc.close();
  pc = null;
  callButton.disabled = false;
  hangupButton.disabled = true;
  console.log('Call Ended');
}
```

**index.js**

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var app = (module.exports.app = express());
var path = require('path');

var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
const PORT_NO = process.env.APP_PORT || 3000;
server.listen(PORT_NO);

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.sendFile(path.resolve('./index.html'));
});

app.use(express.static('.'));
io.on('connection', socket => {
  function log() {
    const array = ['Message from server:'];
    for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      array.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    socket.emit('log', array);
  }

  socket.on('message', message => {
    log('Got message:', message);
    socket.broadcast.emit('message', message);
  });

  socket.on('create or join', room => {
    var clientsInRoom = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[room];
    var numClients = clientsInRoom
      ? Object.keys(clientsInRoom.sockets).length
      : 0;

    // max two clients
    if (numClients === 2) {
      socket.emit('full', room);
      return;
    }

    log('Room ' + room + ' now has ' + (numClients + 1) + ' client(s)');

    if (numClients === 0) {
      socket.join(room);
      log('Client ID ' + socket.id + ' created room ' + room);
      socket.emit('created', room, socket.id);
    } else {
      log('Client ID ' + socket.id + ' joined room ' + room);
      io.sockets.in(room).emit('join', room);
      socket.join(room);
      socket.emit('joined', room, socket.id);
      io.sockets.in(room).emit('ready');
    }
  });
});
```

[image: Callee side (in Safari)]

[image: Caller side (in Firefox)]

Answer (score 0):

Let the joiner be the initiator.

I'm guessing `'created'` happens before `'joined'`? I.e. one party creates the room before the second party joins it?

Since your `startVideo()` does more than start the local video—it actually begins connection negotiation—I suspect you begin negotiating before the second party is ready, a race. Instead try:

```
socket.on('created', function(room) {
  console.log('Created room ' + room);
  startVideo();
});

socket.on('joined', function(room) {
  console.log('joined: ' + room);
  isInitiator = true; // <-- begin negotiating once 2nd party arrives.
  startVideo();
});
```

Comment: startVideo() doesn't do the negotiation isn't it? I have the callStart() function which creates the offer to the peer. You are correct that created happens before joined but by changing the isInitiator to the peer that joins, the creator is now unable to press the call button as it would not trigger the createOffer. I am attaching an image for you to take a look which is what comes out from the createOffer https://imgur.com/a/Tgxyu7M.

Comment: @RjTng Ah right. I'm used to people using `onnegotiationneeded`.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a call to `createPeerConnection()` on the answerer side, which means the answerer isn't properly set up to signal ICE candidates or fire the track event.

You only call it from `startCall()`, so this would only work if you hit the call button on both ends at almost exactly the same time.

`createPeerConnection()` is a misnomer. Instead, just initialize the `pc` with its `ontrack` and `onicecandidate` callbacks on page load.

#### Still not working?

The rest of your WebRTC-related code you're showing us looks fine—except you're calling `getUserMedia` twice on the answerer side, which is redundant, but shouldn't be a problem.

I suspect a bug in your server logic. E.g. you're not showing us how emitting `'create or join'` turns into either a `'created'` or `'joined'` socket message. You're also trying to predetermine which side is which in the offer/answer exchange, which is fine, except this means you have a non-working `Call` button on the answerer side. Most demos just let whoever pushes the button first be the offerer, though that might create glare. Just FYI.

#### This is a two-way call. In which direction is remoteVideo not working?

Also, you have a two-way call here, sending video in *both* directions, yet you've not mentioned *which* remoteVideo you're not seeing.

For a working example, check out my [two-way tab demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/jyysn48t/). Open it in two adjacent windows in the same browser, and click the `Call` button in *one* of them to connect. You should see (the same) video being sent both ways. It relies on a `localSocket` hack using localStorage.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite get what u are saying. pc has already been configured at the start with `var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);` but I did try to add another `createPeerConnection()` where the offer message is received but it does not create the remote video stream.

Comment: @RjTng That's what I meant.

Comment: Both sides of the remote video isn't working. I went to try to start the room on a phone, the local video would be able to be displayed but after pressing the call button it immediately shuts off. This was after adding the PeerConnection to the offer case and commenting out the redundant getUserMedia.  Been trying to do it on localhost too and comparing my code with yours it seems like its correct.

Comment: for the socket.io signalling, I would think its correct as its from the codelabs 
`if (numClients === 0) {
      socket.join(room);
      log('Client ID ' + socket.id + ' created room ' + room);
      socket.emit('created', room, socket.id);
    } else if (numClients === 1) {
      log('Client ID ' + socket.id + ' joined room ' + room);
      io.sockets.in(room).emit('join', room);
      socket.join(room);
      socket.emit('joined', room, socket.id);
      io.sockets.in(room).emit('ready', room);
    } else {
      // max two clients
      socket.emit('full', room);
    }`

Comment: Codelabs? Hah. I've shown you a working version, so hopefully you'll be able to find out how your code differs, and get it working. Good luck!

Comment: Hi sorry, I just need to check one more thing. Must the ICE candidates finish gathering (NULL) before the remote video can be displayed or it does not matter

Comment: @RjTng Maybe ask as a question?